# Connect to Circuit API using on-premise company account

Tags: circuit-sdk

How can I connect circuit api with my current company circuit account and use it to send outlook meeting requests? When I try to access via the below javascript code, it keeps on showing login via active directory and after successful login it again returns back to the circuit login page.

```
        let client = new Circuit.Client({

        client_id: '1ad87bda8c8a48678fdb86d31d1*****',


        scope: 'ALL',
        domain: 'circuit.siemens.com',
        //redirect_uri: 'localhost:29651'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Moved my comment as answer so question can be marked as "answered".

There is no Circuit API to send outlook meeting requests. You can call https://circuitsandbox.net/sdk/classes/Client.html#method_getConversationDetails to get the meeting invitation text (dial in numbers, guest link etc), but the actual meeting request would need to be sent with an exchange API.

Regarding the Active Directory login, I am not sure what the problem is exactly. I assume you registered an IMPLICIT app and received the above client_id. No need to pass a redirect_uri, but make sure the redirect uri you registered as is where you host your app.

Comment: Then how does add to circuit conversation work in Outlook. I am asking about the circuit connector with Outlook which can send the meeting details on circuit. How can I implement that functionality in an Application ?

Comment: I am not clear what functionality you want to implement in your application. Please provide more details about your application and what you want to achieve.

The "Circuit for Outlook" connector in outlook uses an internal API to the Circuit backend since its written in C# and the Circuit SDK is javascript.

Comment: I want to use the internal API that the "Circuit for Outlook" connector uses. Basically my application should have the feature of "Add to circuit conversation" while sending a Meeting Request. My application is used to send meeting requests so I want to add that functionality of "Add to circuit conversation" to my application.

Comment: Internal APIs are internal to Circuit components. These API may change at any time without notice. You cannot use those APIs. The C4O "Add to Circuit Conversation" has two options: 1) Create new conversation... and 2) Add to existing conversation. 

For 1) you need the APIs: createGroupConversation, getConferenceInvitationText and then addTextItem to post the appointment text to Circuit. For moderation and guest access you'd use moderateConversation and disabledGuestAccess. For 2) instead of createConversation you need getConversations and optionally the search APIs.